# How to make x and y flip for an image as like Jquery resizable UI with handles..?

Tags: jquery, css, image, jquery-ui, flip

I need to flip an image with x and y axis, i already used Jquery UI for resize and rotate. But can't able to do flip an image. I viewed lot of plugins to make flip image, but those are gets flip automatically with a single click or any-other events., but i need like to handle with user-defined positions with handles.

```
 $("img").css({"width":"100px","height":"100px"}).resizable({handles:'ne,se,nw,sw'}).parent().draggable();
```

JQuery UI resize and drag sample in link [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/L1z8mdx2/9/)..!

Comment: What would activate the flip? Reverse on the horizontal or vertical?

Answer (score 1):

Without know more, you can see an example of how to flip the image:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/bncxeu1c/3/

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <a id="x" href="#">Flip X</a> <a id="y" href="#">Flip Y</a>
  <div>
    <img class="front up" src="http://placehold.it/80x80/c9112d/fff&text=1" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-resizable-se {
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.ui-resizable {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

// Flip on Y
.front {
  transform: none;
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

//Flip on X
.up {
  transform: none;
}

.down {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").css({
    "width": "100px",
    "height": "100px"
  }).resizable({
    handles: 'ne,se,nw,sw'
  }).parent().draggable();

  $("#y").click(function() {
    if ($("img").hasClass("front")) {
      $("img").removeClass("front").addClass("back");
    } else {
      $("img").removeClass("back").addClass("front");
    }
  });

  $("#x").click(function() {
    if ($("img").hasClass("up")) {
      $("img").removeClass("up").addClass("down");
    } else {
      $("img").removeClass("down").addClass("up");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But i need to handle it with user defined flip., not with any click event. I need to do flip like a resize works with handles.....

Comment: Is there any way to do like that one..? Or any reference link..?

Comment: Will need more info.

Comment: Need to flip the image using the resize button(bottom-right corner) while click and drag that button...

Comment: So what should the user do to flip versus resize?

Comment: Yes i understand why you are asking this question. I will give more information: For example if i need do horizontal flip, using that resize button while decreasing the width to 8px (can do this now with resize button), further i need to make horizontal drag to 0px, if it reaches to 0px the image need to flip, for further i need to increase the width in opposite direction to view the flipped image. These are only i need to done with that resize button without any external onclick function. Please help me.. Thanks in Advance.....!

Comment: So if the drag handle crosses over 0 on X or Y, you want the image to flip respectively?

Comment: Yes.. Is it possible..?

Comment: @ArunValaven the short answer is no, not with JQuery UI Resizable. IT will not cross into a negative margin. Possible scenario would be to use 4 `div` elements, and when the handle reaches a specific threshold, move the image, flipped, into one of the other quadrants, change the handle location and allow that new element be resized.

Comment: Thanks for your clear reply.. Is there any other plugins or any other code you know to achieve my above said functionality..(other than Jquery UI)., share with me.. Thanks for your kind reply till now..

Comment: @ArunValaven You mentioned you found a number of plugins that can do this. I would find one of these that seems to do what you want, and I am sure there is a way to trigger it's operation the way you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107157/discussion-between-arunvalaven-and-twisty).

Comment: @ArunValaven take a look at this: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fvremenno.net%2Fjs%2Fjquery-ui-rotation-using-css-transform%2F

Comment: @ArunValaven - Since that plugin, which works for JQuery 1.4.2, is old, I adapted some of it's functions: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/bncxeu1c/9/ Will need a lot more work and I might develop it into a modern plugin. It will just take time.